# Django: How to display Multiple Models in a single view through function approach?

Tags: django

what I want to execute that all my three models will be displayed through one view by a function approach.
The fields I want to display in
All fields of Cylinder Entry ,issue date(if exists) ,userName,Return date(if exists)
(of that particular cylinderId)

Eg:

```
 cylinderId | date  | type | status |availability|    issuedate     | userName | returndate |
    
           1      11/11   co2    fill    available    12/11(if exists)    xyz        13/11(if exists)
```

Sorry for this messy table.
but unable to write the logic please help me out

here is my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class CylinderEntry(models.Model):
    stachoice=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty') 
    ]
    substachoice=[
    ('Available','availabe'), 
    
    ]
    cylinderId=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    gasName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cylinderSize=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=stachoice,default='fill')
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=substachoice,default="Available")
    EntryDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cylinderDetail',args=[(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cylinderId


class IssueCylinder(models.Model):
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('CylinderEntry',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=60,null=False)
    issueDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability=('Issued'))

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        
        return str(self.userName) 


class ReturnCylinder(models.Model):
    fill=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty'),
    ('refill','Refill')
    ]

    ava=[
    ('yes','YES'),
    ('no','NO')
    ]
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('CylinderEntry',on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=True)
    user_return=models.ForeignKey('IssueCylinder',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    returnDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=fill)
    availability=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=ava)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:

            if self.availability=='YES' or self.availability=='yes':
                CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Available')
            else:
                CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Unavailable')
                if self.status=='refill' or self.status=='Refill':
                    CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Refill')


        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cylinder
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have linked your model tables with ForeignKeys you can simply access each cylender object's properties in the other two tables as if you would do it if it were from the same table

I can see you were not able to write the logic so i will provide you with a sample code

```
def CylinderView(request):
  cylinders = CylinderEntry.objects.all()
  return render(request,'renderCylinder.html', {'cylinders':cylinders})
```

Now this will send `cylinders` as context to the html page `renderCylinder.html` where it can be displayed like this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>cylinderId</th>
    <th>type</th>
<th>status</th>
<th>availability</th>
<th>issuedate</th>
<th>userName</th>
<th>returndate</th>
  </tr>
{% for cylinder in cylinders %}
<tr>
<td>{{cylinder.cylinderId}}</td>
<td>{{cylinder.type}}</td>
<td>{{cylinder.status}}</td>
<td>{{cylinder.availability}}</td>
<td>{{cylinder.issuedate}}</td>
<td>{{cylinder.userName}}</td>
<td>{{cylinder.returndate}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer but it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
def cylinderListView(request):
    cylinder=CylinderEntry.objects.all().values('cylinderId','EntryDate','gasName','Status','Availability','issuecylinder__userName','issuecylinder__issueDate','returncylinder__returnDate')

    return render(request,'entry/cylinderList.html',{'cylinder':cylinder})
```